# How do I close a PDF file in VB.net after user closes it?

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.net. I would like to know if I can delete a PDF file after user closes it. In my VB.net application, Users can open files in pdf format if they select the pdf option. But I want the file to be deleted once the user closes the PDF file.

I googled it and came across this piece of code in c#

```
var pdfProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\test.pdf");
pdfProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(pdfProcess_Exited);
pdfProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

 void pdfProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(@"c:\test.pdf);
        }
```

I was wondering if this could be done in VB.net

I am creating the file first and then open it by
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\TEMP\myFile.pdf")

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a suitable solution. You are aware that there are automatic C#->VB converters on the web? BTW: Being able to read C# is a useful skill for VB developers, since many .NET examples on the web are in C#.

Comment: Its not working in this case, thanks for the info though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the process object from the toolbox as I find it easier to look through the properties. I found it confusing when my simple code would not work with the .HasExited but I found out that you have to instruct the object to wait for the exit so I coded the program. So I found the solution to your problem I think.

```
Process1.Start("Your file path")
Process1.WaitForExit()

If Process1.HasExited Then
System.IO.File.Delete("Your File Path")
End If
```